# inserting data on mysql using vb.net with VS2010

Tags: mysql, vb.net, visual-studio-2010

im trying to insert data in mysql  but i just cant do it ive tried to search for answers on  the net and tried everything on my code but it just wont insert [here is the image of the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TSrnV.jpg)
hope some one can help me and thanks in advance ... MERRY CHRISTMAS !!

here is the code

```
    myconn = New MySqlConnection
    myconn.ConnectionString = "host=127.0.0.1;user=root;password=;database=engr_log"
    Dim Reader As MySqlDataReader
    Try
        myconn.Open()
        Dim query As String
        query = "insert into log_tbl ('ID', 'owner_name', 'business_name', 'Amount_paid', 'Location', 'Date') values (NULL, '" & txtname.Text & "','" & txtbus.Text & "','" & txtamount.Text & "', '" & txtloc.Text & "','" & dtp1.Value & "');"
       command = New MySqlCommand(query, myconn)
        Reader = command.ExecuteReader
        MessageBox.Show("Entry Saved!!","SAVE", MessageBoxButtons.OK, MessageBoxIcon.Information)
        myconn.Close()
    Catch ex As Exception
        MsgBox(ex.Message.ToString)
    End Try
    getlist()
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the single quotes around the column in your insert statment:

`insert into log_tbl (ID, owner_name, business_name, Amount_paid, Location, Date`)...

But the bigger problem is you should use queries with parameters to not only avoid errors but also SQL injections.

Example:

```
Dim connectionString = "host=127.0.0.1;user=root;password=;database=engr_log"
Dim query = "insert into log_tbl (owner_name, business_name, Amount_paid, Location, Date) values (@owner_name, @business_name, @Amount_paid, @Location, @Date);"
Using connection As New MySqlConnection(connectionString)
    Dim command As New MySqlCommand(query, connection)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owner_name", txtname.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@business_name", txtbus.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Amount_paid", txtamount.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Location", txtloc.Text)
    command.Parameters.AddWithValue("@Date", dtp1.Text)
    command.Connection.Open()
    command.ExecuteNonQuery()
End Using
```

Even better, you can be explicit with the types:

```
command.Parameters.Add("@owner_name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
command.Parameters.Add("@business_name", SqlDbType.VarChar)
command.Parameters.Add("@Amount_paid", SqlDbType.Float)
command.Parameters.Add("@Location", SqlDbType.VarChar)
command.Parameters.Add("@Date", SqlDbType.DateTime)
```

Comment: Thanks sir your suggestion works but i just have i minor problem how do i combine the the parameters with addvalue :

Comment: You need to give me more details, this code is not tested

Comment: Sorry I did'nt notice that I entered my comment with an incomplete content 
what I mean is how do I combine the normal parameter which is 

.Parameters.AddWithValue("@owner_name", txtname.Text)

 with the one with explicit type 

.Parameters.Add("@owner_name",SqlDbType.Varchar)

Comment: You cannot combine, you choose one or the other, `AddWithValue` leaves in up to the DB server to determine the types

Comment: Ok I get it ... ill stick with the first idea. Thanks for your help , much appreciated

Comment: Your welcome, please accept the answer, Happy holidays :)